# Are getters and setters needed for CDI injected beans?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, inject

When a bean is injected using CDI:

```
@Inject Person person;
```

Is a setter and getter needed/recommended?

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class myJSFBean{

  @Inject Person person;

  public void setPerson (Person person){
    this.person = person;
  }
  public Person getPerson (){
    return person;
  }
```

I have found this documentation, but I don't understand what it means:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: This example is more about JSF managed Bean used with CDI annotation, where you need getter/Setter. Elsewhere there's no need to have getter/setter in a CDI bean.

Comment: I am using JSF, but not the JSF annotations (eg ManagedBean) instead I'm using @Named. So if I am not using JSF the getter/setter is not needed?

Comment: Just remove them, test the code and figure by yourself? Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383446/do-i-need-getter-for-the-injected-conversation-interface-in-cdi-bean

Comment: @MarkW : no, not needed if you do not use JSF.

Comment: @RC. I saw that question and believed it to be something to do with injecting a Conversation  into a ConversationScoped bean. I'm not familiar with either concept.

Comment: Getters are still useful when other beans injecting this one want to access the variables (the encapsulation still holds). Setters, on the other hand, might be even dangerous as someone could use it to set an unmanaged object into the field (unmanaged = not created by CDI, typically created by manually calling `new` which won't work as you expect).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Weld Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html_single/#_getting_our_feet_wet):

> Notice that it isn’t necessary to create a getter or setter method to inject one bean into another. CDI can access an injected field directly (even if it’s private!), which sometimes helps eliminate some wasteful code. The name of the field is arbitrary. It’s the field’s type that determines what is injected.

Answer (score 3):

*CDI* (*Container Dependency Injection*) within *Java EE* 6 application can target different injection points: **fields, constructors and setters**.

So the short answer is **no**, you do not need a *setter* method if you won't be using it as the injection point.

The *getter* can be ignored as well unless you need one to access the field state (which by experience does not make much sence in a *CDI* environment, the same field that has been injected by the container still can be accessed through it in other components).

Answer (score 0):

I would even consider a getter harmful.

Due to the encapsulation principle, getters and setters are **public** by default in most IDEs and in your example above, too. This means you pollute your autocomplete with CDI injects. These shouldn't be visible outside of your class.

If you access an `@ApplicationScoped` been via a getter in a `@RequestScoped` bean, the request scoped bean will always be instantiated needlessly, which costs performance. CDI beans should always be injected where they are needed and not being accessed across beans. You will prevent CDI from handling your scopes correctly.

So all there is really left is a *private* getter, which is superfluous anyway, because you will never have to modify a cdi bean before you return it.